# Что это значит

Tags: фразеология

Что значит фразеологическое словосочетание "жаренные факты"? Мне срочно нужен ответ)

Comment: @Delete 0711, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Жареные факты - сенсационные негативные сведения.

Answer (score 1):

У американских газетчиков "жареное" - "новость, несущая угрозу для репутации кого-либо". Значение заимствовано русскими газетчиками как "жареные факты о *(далее следует известное имя или название организации)*".
Проследить происхождение термина в иностранном профессиональном жаргоне затрудняюсь. Однако, рискну предположить, что "жареным" именовали сведения, публикация которых несёт угрозу для газеты или журналиста (сведения, об которые можно "обжечься").

Comment: А может быть, это запах жареного?

Comment: Как "запах жареного" ассоциируется с "угрозой для репутации"?

Comment: Когда вы чувствует запах жареного, то это может быть "угрозой" для  мяса на вашей плите.

Comment: Устойчивое выражение "пахнет жареным" означает непосредственную (обычно - смертельную) опасность для того, кому "пахнет". Обычно данное выражение "выводят" из костров инквизиции. Возможна и альтернативная трактовка, популярная среди тех, кто часто ночует у костра... Однако, к приготовлению пищи данное выражение отношения не имеет.  
В нашем случае "пахнуть жареным" может либо для распространителя "жареных фактов", либо - для того, о ком они распространяются..  
Первая версия - близка к предложенной мной. Вторая - кажется мне не слишком вероятной.

Answer (score 1):

Из словаря ненормативной лексики

ЖАРЕНОЕ - что-либо сенсационное, чреватое драматическими последствиями: "...весь народ, разинув рот, следил за "жареным".

ПАХНЕТ ЖАРЕНЫМ - дело принимает плохой оборот: "Надо было сильно спешить потому, что бой приближался к нам: слева чьи-то танки гремят, справа стрельба идет, впереди стрельба, и уже начало попахивать жареным" (М. Шолохов).